# mips assembly code to shift the bit programming

Tags: assembly, while-loop, bit-shift, mips32, instruction-set

Read in your Student ID and save it to a register, and read in the number “10010000x” as the initial 
    memory address.  Then shift your student ID number to the right one bit at a time, and save it to 
    the memory address which is 4 bytes increment from the previous memory address, until your 
    student ID number is smaller than 1, then save your final student ID number which is NOT smaller 
    than 1, and save the last memory address, and how many iterations to 3 different memory 
    addresses.  Turn in the hardcopy of the MARS graphic printout which has the MIPS Assembly 
    code showing your student ID, and memory addresses and all registers values, and also answer 
    the following three questions on the hard copy paper :
    (1) How many shift right you have to do to get your student ID number to be smaller than 1 ?
    (2) What is your last NOT smaller than 1 binary student id number ? 
    (3) What is the last memory address that saves that last NOT smaller than 1 student ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li $t0, 0x10010000
li $t1, student id
li $s3, 1
li $s5, 1
add $s0, $t0, $zero
add $s1, $t1, $zero
loop1 : sw $s1, 0($s0)
srl $s2, $s1, 1
slt $s4, $s2, $s3
beq $s4, $s3, L2
addi $s0, $s0, 4
add $s1, $s2, $zero
add $s5,$s5,$s3
j  loop1
L2 : addi $s0, $s0, 4
sw $s5, 4($s0)
sw $s2, 8($s0)
addi $t3, $s0, -4
sw $t3, 12($s0)
```